# What toLowerCase alternative could I use here?

Tags: javascript, comparison

I'm trying to look through the 'text' variable for the name 'bob', and count how many times I find it. When comparing the text with the name 'bob' I find myself needing to use toLowerCase, because b != B. But then the loop fails when it tries to convert a blank space into lowercase.

What could I do about this? Also, I'd appreciate any suggestions to improve my code-- I'm still a beginner.

```js
var text = "Hey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob";

var myName = "bob";
var temp = [];
var lower = '';
var count = 0;
var hits = 0;

var valid = function(letter) {

  if (myName[count] == undefined) {
    count = 0;
  }

  var
  let = letter.toLowerCase();

  if (let === myName[count]) {
    temp.push(let);
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 0;
    temp.pop(let);
    return false;
  }

  if (myName == temp.join("")) {
    hits += 1;
    temp = [];
  }

};

for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {

  if (text[i] === "b") {

    for (var j = i; j < (myName.length + i); j++) {

      lower = text[j].toLowerCase();

      if (valid(lower) == false) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

if (hits == 0) {
  console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
  console.log(hits);
} else {
  console.log(hits);
}
```

Comment: `let` has meaning in newer JS so I would not use that as a variable name

Answer (score 2):

The specific error you are getting is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`. This is happening because in your inner `for` loop you are running past the end of the `text` string. You need to check that `j < text.length`:

```
for (var j = i; j < (myName.length + i) && j < text.length; j++) {
```

That way you know that `text[j]` will have a defined value so `text[j].toLowerCase()` will work and your code will run.

I think you have some other logic errors, but I don't have time to properly debug it for you, especially when your requirement can be implemented in one line by using [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a regex:

```
hits = text.split(/\bbob\b/i).length-1;
```

Or a more dynamic version:

```js
var text = "Hey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I don't like bobbing. Bob";
var myName = "bob";

var hits = text.split(new RegExp("\\b" + myName + "\\b","i")).length-1;
console.log(hits);
```

Notice that the regex is matching word boundardies around the word using `\b`, so that it will match `'Bob'` but not `'bobbing'` - if you *want* to match `'bobbing'` then simply use `text.split('bob').length-1`.

Notice also that by using a regex with the `i` flag it does a case insensitve match.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance it is better to use a regular expression to find the text that you require:

```
var re = /(bob)/gi; 
var str = 'Hey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob\nHey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob\nHey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob\nHey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob\n';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: Given the OP's requirement seems to be just to count the occurrences, couldn't you replace the `while` loop with something like `(str.match(re)||[]).length`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing that:

```
var text = "Hey, how are you doing? My name is Bob. I like to sleep. Bob";
var myName = "bob";
var re = new RegExp("\\b"+myName+"\\b","ig"); // \b==wordBoundary;i==igonoreCase;g==searchMultiple;
var m = text.match(re);
if (m==null) {
  console.log("Your name wasn't found!");
  console.log(0);
} else {
  console.log(m.length);  
}
```